# No SQL Server Name

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, connect

Today I installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to install the sample database Northwind. After installing the program, I opened it and at the startup page under "Connect to server" there was a field called "Server name". I am totally new to databases so I couldn't figure out what I should do. I did a quick search on the internet and tried "SQLCMD -L" command in cmd to see available servers but instead, it returned;

```
;UID:Login ID=?;PWD:Password=?;Trusted_Connection:Use Integrated Security=?;*APP:Ap pName=?;*WSID:WorkStation ID=?;
```

So it seems like I don't have a database (at least as I understand it so).

Can you help me to install this sample in SMSS?

P.S.: I use Windows 7

Comment: Did you install SQL Server? Also, you know Windows 7 is now **completely** unsupported now, right? (How could you not if I'm honest, the world has been telling you for at least a year.)

Comment: i know win7 is not supported but i can not do anything about it now. Could you please tell me how can i install SQL Server? I installed SSMS

Comment: *"Could you please tell me how can i install SQL Server?"* By downloading SQL Server and then installing it, just like you did with SSMS. Note that none of the supported (SQL Server) versions support Windows 7, so cannot be installed on it. You will need to install one that is only in extended support.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the name of the instance of the Database Engine

1-Log into Windows as a member of the Administrators group, and open Management Studio.

2-In the Connect to Server dialog box, click Cancel.

3-If Registered Servers is not displayed, on the View menu, click Registered Servers.

4-With Database Engine selected on the Registered Servers toolbar, expand Database Engine, right-click Local Server Groups, point to Tasks, and then click Register Local Servers. Expand Local Server Groups to see all the instances of the Database Engine installed on the computer displayed. The default instance is unnamed and is shown as the computer name. A named instance displays as the computer name followed by a backward slash () and then the name of the instance. For SQL Server Express, the instance is named \sqlexpress unless the name was changed during setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to a local database just type a dot(`.`) or type (localhost) and click on connect button

[image]

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to ..

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: The OP has clearly not installed SQL Server. As they are using an unsupported version of Windows, the latest version they can install is 2014; which is also only in extended support.